# REST Jersey+jackson servlet parsea parte del json como un JsonObject

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

Estoy recibiendo un JSON que jersey+jackson me lo parsea directamente en el objeto que contendrá la información. La cosa es que quiero que parte de ese JSON, se guarde como un **JSONObject o JSONArray**.

Este sería el JSON que se recibe,

```
 {  
  "fecha":"2018-10-03",
  "fechaCoste":"2018-10-30",
  "idTipoParte":1,
  "idEstado":1,
  "actividades":[  
     {  
        "idParteActividad":282,
        "idTipoActividad":3,
           "idPadre":5,
           "type":"farm",
           "key":"11265,14",
           "idModulo":9,
           "modulo":"ACTIVITIES",
        "data":[  
           {  
              "idParteActividadData":131,
              "idField":3,
              "value":123456
           },
           {  
              "idParteActividadData":132,
              "idField":4,
              "value":2.0
           }
        ],
        "descripcion":"test",
        "recursos":[  
           {  
              "idPerfilTrab":17,
              "cantidadObj":0.0,
              "idParteRecurso":264,
              "idTipoRecurso":1,
              "idRecurso":25,
              "cantidad":1.0,
              "idTipoUd":1,
              "importeUd":0.0,
              "costeUd":0.0
           },
           {  
              "idParteRecurso":140,
              "idTipoRecurso":2,
              "idRecurso":2,
              "cantidad":1.0,
              "idTipoUd":1,
              "importeUd":0.0,
              "costeUd":0.0
           },
           {  
              "tipoMvto":"I",
              "idAlmacen":3,
              "idPersona":25,
              "idTipoStock":1,
              "lote":"1",
              "albaran":"1",
              "idParteRecurso":215,
              "idTipoRecurso":3,
              "idRecurso":20,
              "cantidad":1.0,
              "idTipoUd":1,
              "importeUd":1.0,
              "costeUd":0.0
           }
        ],
        "cost":0.0
     }
  ]

}
```

Este seria el objeto en el cual se guardaría el JSON.

```
public class Workpart extends Identifiable {

    private Integer idParte;
    private String fecha;
    private String fechaCoste;
    private String idTipoParte;
    private String idEstado;

    private JsonArray actividades;

    public Workpart() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer id() {
        return getIdParte();
    }

    public Integer getIdParte() {
        return idParte;
    }

    public void setIdParte(final Integer idParte) {
        this.idParte = idParte;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(final String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getFechaCoste() {
        return fechaCoste;
    }

    public void setFechaCoste(final String fechaCoste) {
        this.fechaCoste = fechaCoste;
    }

    public String getIdTipoParte() {
        return idTipoParte;
    }

    public void setIdTipoParte(final String idTipoParte) {
        this.idTipoParte = idTipoParte;
    }

    public String getIdEstado() {
        return idEstado;
    }

    public void setIdEstado(final String idEstado) {
        this.idEstado = idEstado;
    }

    public JsonArray getActividades() {
        return actividades;
    }

    public void setActividades(final JsonArray actividades) {
        this.actividades = actividades;
    }
}
```

Del JSON los primeros campos se guardan en sus correspondientes campos pero quiero que **lo que forma parte del nodo "actividades" se guarde todo como un JSON en el objeto "workpart"**

Se que lo normal sería crear objetos para actividades y recursos con sus correspondientes campos, pero no es factible ya que hay una gran cantidad de distintas actividades con campos distintos que hace más sencillo guardarlo como JSON.

El servicio que se encarga de manejar la llamada REST post es el siguiente.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response insert(@PathParam(USER_ID) final Integer userId, final Workpart record) {
    return insertInner(userId, record);
}
```

Con lo que hay actualmente se produce un pete en el cual dice que no puede parsear actividades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No acabo de ver la ventaja de trabajar con un `JSONArray`, pero lo que necesitas es crear tu propio *des-serializador* para hacer lo que quieres. Si estás trabajando con Jackson, tienes que crear una clase que extienda [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html):

```
public class JsonArrayDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<JsonArray> {

    //constructores...


    public JsonArray deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
         final TreeNode treeNode = parser.readValueAsTree();
         return new com.google.gson.JsonParser()
              .parse(treeNode.toString()).getAsJsonArray();
    }
}
```

Necesitarás mirar el API de [`JsonParser`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html). No es complicada de entender pero tiene muchos métodos para recorrer un JSON.

Y luego necesitas anotar el campo:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonArrayDeserializer.class)
private JsonArray actividades;
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias.

Quedo así al final.

  final TreeNode treeNode = parser.readValueAsTree();                 
  return new com.google.gson.JsonParser().parse(treeNode.toString()).getAsJsonArray();

Comment: Realmente me valía o un JsonArray o  un JsonObject

Comment: Pongo tu código en en la respuesta